Formula for higher-order derivatives of the logarithm of a function, $\frac {d^m}{dx^m} \log h(x)$
I am trying to see if I can get a general formula for the $m$th derivative of the logarithm of a function. Specifically, I am trying to find the $m$th derivative of $g(x) = \log h(x)$.
Let $h^{(m)}(x) = \frac {d^m}{dx^m} h(x)$ denote the $m$th derivative of $h(x)$.
Then, we see that the first derivative is
\begin{equation}
\frac d{dx} g(x) = \frac{h^{(1)}(x)}{h(x)}
\end{equation}
while the second derivative is
\begin{equation}
\frac {d^2}{dx^2}g(x) = \frac{h^{(2)}(x)}{h(x)} - \left[\frac{h^{(1)}(x)}{h(x)}\right]^2,
\end{equation}
and the third derivative is
\begin{equation}
\frac {d^3}{dx^3}g(x) = \frac{h^{(3)}(x)}{h(x)} - \frac{3h^{(1)}(x)h^{(2)}(x)}{h^2(x)} +  2\left[\frac{h^{(1)}(x)}{h(x)}\right]^3,
\end{equation}
and the fourth derivative is
\begin{equation}
\frac {d^4}{dx^4}g(x) = \frac{h^{(4)}(x)}{h(x)} - \frac{h^{(3)}(x)h^{(1)}(x)}{h^2(x)} - 3\left[\frac{h^{(2)}(x)}{h(x)}\right]^2 - 3\frac{h^{(1)}(x)h^{(3)}(x)}{h^2(x)} +   \frac{12[h^{(1)}(x)]^2h^{(2)}(x)}{h^3(x)} - 6\left[\frac{h^{(1)}(x)}{h(x)}\right]^4.
\end{equation}
But I can not see a way to specify a general formula for the $m$th order derivative of $g(x)$. Is there such a general formula possible?
Many thanks for any pointers and suggestions!

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula

You can write it in terms of $\frac{d^m}{dx^m}h(x)^j$, which can be simplified for certain functions, like in the “Log from function” section here or using $\ln(x)$’s limit representation.

Thank you @ТymaGaidash how would I use the limit representation of $\log x$?  I am not sure.

This computation is a direct application of Faà di Bruno's formula, a generalization of the chain rule to higher-order derivatives. It can be expressed efficiently in terms of the incomplete Bell polynomials $B_{m, k}$, which encode the relevant combinatorial data:
$$(f \circ h)^{(m)}(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^m f^{(k)}(g(x)) B_{m, k}\left(h'(x), h''(x), \ldots, h^{(m - k + 1)}(x)\right) .$$
If you prefer, you can express $B_{m, k}$ in terms of the Stirling numbers of the second kind.
Differentiating $f(x) = \log x$ a total of $k > 0$ times gives $f^{(k)}(u) = \frac{(-1)^k (k - 1)!}{u^k}$, and substituting gives for $m > 0$ (in particular using that $B_{m, 0} = 0$ for $m > 0$) that
$$\boxed{(\log h)^{(n)}(x) = \sum_{k = 1}^m \frac{(-1)^k (k - 1)!}{h(x)^k} B_{m, k}\left(h'(x), h''(x), \ldots, h^{(m - k + 1)}(x)\right)}.$$
Example $(m = 3)$ We need
$$\color{#bf0000}{B_{3, 1}(y_1, y_2, y_3) = y_3}, \quad \color{#00bf00}{B_{3, 2}(y_1, y_2) = 3 y_1 y_2}, \quad \color{#0000ff}{B_{3, 3}(y_1) = y_1^3}.$$
Substituting in Faà di Bruno's formula then gives
$$(\log h)^{(3)}(x) = \frac{\color{#bf0000}{h'''(x)}}{h(x)} - \frac{\color{#00bf00}{3 h''(x) h'(x)}}{h(x)^2} + \frac{2 \color{#0000ff}{h'(x)^3}}{h(x)^3} .$$
